# Javascript/Jscript.NET :How do I append a string to search query only once?

Tags: javascript, append

In this case, Let's take Google as example:

The code is JScript .NET, which is basically a .NET version of Javascript.Regardless of language, Anyone with appending type of skill can answer my question

The problem is, when I keep issuing the request it keeps appending over and over again, https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyB3K.png

```
if (oSession.uriContains("q=")) 
{
    var str = oSession.fullUrl;
    var sAppend = "+test1+test2+test3";
    if (!oSession.uriContains(sAppend))
    {
        oSession.fullUrl = str.replace( "q=","q="+sAppend);
    }
}
```

Thank you.

**Notice**: When I type from main page Google starts like `search?site=&source=hp&q=&oq=`, then after the first append it turns into `search?q=&oq=`

Comment: After you've already appended, you have to look at why this is true again   oSession.uriContains("q=")

Comment: @Seano666 I know, but How do I write the code? I'm new to programming

Comment: What happens in this function?  uriContains()

Comment: @Seano666 uriContains()// It checks,case Insensitive String From URI. [More Info](http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/13-07-15/understanding-fiddlerscript)

Comment: Try this inside of the if statement before you do your replace.  alert(str);  This will show you the second time what the url is and why the condition does not think that it contains the sAppend string.

Comment: @Seano666 I tried this `alert(str); { oSession.fullUrl = str.replace( "q=","q="+sAppend); }`  it says"variable `alert` has not been declared"

Comment: @Seano666 Also this other code works with youtube, but not with google.     `if (oSession.uriContains("search_query=")) 
 {
 var str = oSession.fullUrl;
 var sAppend = "+test1+test2+test3";
 if (oSession.fullUrl.indexOf(sAppend, str.length - sAppend.length) < 0)
 {
 oSession.fullUrl = str + sAppend;
 }
 }`